Delete Registry Key if empty (One line code)
I'm trying to do a one line batch command that would delete a Key if it's empty. Below are 2 solutions that should work be for some strange reason they don't. 
For /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('Reg Query "HKCU\Software\RandomKey" 2^>NUL ^| FindStr /l /i /c:"\\Software\\RandomKey\\"') do (EXIT) ^& Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\RandomKey" /f 1>NUL

For /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('Reg Query "HKCU\Software\RandomKey" 2^>NUL ^| FindStr /l /i /c:"\\Software\\RandomKey\\"') do Set "FSK=1" ^& If Not "%FSK%"=="1" Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\RandomKey" /f 1>NUL


The first: EXIT will exit the batch, so the remainder will be skipped. The second because the entire logical line is parsed, any %var% replaced with its then-current value, and then executed, hence any change in FSK will be ignored and the code executed on the value of fsk at the time.Variables are not behaving as expected. Use do if errorlevel 1… to detect whether the string was NOT found.

The EXIT was a workaround idea to exit the script when the Registry Key is not empty and continue with the script Reg Delete when the Registry Key isn't empty, I also tried it with the If ErrorLevel but the output was always 0.

What's the particular issue with telling us the real registry key branch, and if not empty, what exactly you'd expect to see there. We cannot track you down or steal your soul for this information, but it would increase the chances of receiving an accurate or efficient response.

The content in the SubKey is random and never static.

Here's a test:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR %%y IN ("RandomKey" "GIGABYTE" "Notepad++" "7-zip") DO (
 ECHO testing "%%~y"
 rem show Reg Query output for demonstration
 Reg Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\%%~y" 2>&1
 Reg Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\%%~y" 2>&1|FINDSTR /b /c:"    (Default)">nul&IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO DO whatever
 echo/
) 
GOTO :EOF

On my system:
"RandomKey" Doesn't exist; error message redirected to stdout to avoid clutter

"GIGABYTE" Exists, but is not empty (has subkeys)

"Notepad++" Is empty and generates the message

"7-zip" is not empty.

The findstr command looks for the /c: constant string between quotes (note 4 leading spaces & case-sensitive) at /b the beginning of the line.
Results on my machine
testing "RandomKey"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

testing "GIGABYTE"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GIGABYTE\Control Center
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GIGABYTE\DramInfos
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GIGABYTE\GBT_GCC_Lib

testing "Notepad++"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Notepad++
    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Notepad++

DO whatever

testing "7-zip"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\7-zip
    Path64    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\7-Zip\
    Path    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\7-Zip\


The (Default) text does not exist in the Reg Query output, But I could get it to work with this code line: For %%k in ("RandomSubKey") do (Reg Query "HKCU\Software%%~k" 2>&1 | FindStr /l /i /c:"\Software\RandomSubKey\" >NUL & If ErrorLevel 1 ECHO Reg Delete empty RandomSubKey) Not sure why this works because when I check  ECHO %ErrorLevel% then it always shows 0.

Follow the link in my first comment for an explanation of why you are getting 0 displayed as errorlevel when it has been changed to 1.  I've updated the code to include the reg query results and posted them from my machine.

Oh yeah I forgot the lovely EnableDelayedExpansion again.  Now it works, I also added an updated FindStr to better check if a SubKey is empty -> For %%k in ("RandomSubKey") do (Reg Query "HKCU\Software%%~k" 2>&1 | FindStr /l /i /c:"\Software\RandomSubKey\" /c:"REG_" >NUL & If ErrorLevel 1 ECHO Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\RandomSubKey" /f 1>NUL)
